# Compare package versions of different debian releases

Tags: debian, apt, downgrade, release-management

I installed a server using debian-testing (jessie). Well, I regret it. They already broke the complete system twice because systemd suddenly required additional kernel features.
And I don't want to have so many updates any more...

Before I try to downgrade to stable (wheezy) I would like to compare the package versions of both distributions so I can estimate the impact...

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There isn't really any automated methods.  Why not just setup a VM really quick and install all the requirements into the VM and issue a `dpkg -l`.

Comment: because it's arm. would need qemu, which was a pain in the ass to make it work.